# Cant generate cookie Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, cookies

I want to generate LogIn cookie that can be received by angular. Lets go straight to the code:

Startup.cs

```
Services:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                // Make the session cookie essential
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Cors", builder =>
            {
                builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
              services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie();

            services.AddMvc();
            IntegrateSimpleInjector(services);
        }
```

Configuration:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            InitializeContainer(app);
            container.Verify();
            //app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());

            app.UseCors("Cors");
            // ASP.NET default stuff here
            //login cookies
            app.UseCors(policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
                policy.AllowCredentials();
            });

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

And controller, login details are checked in loginService, here I just return true or false as a response to the angular WITH cookie I cant generate, don't know whats the issue.

```
[Route("Login")]
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginDto loginDto)
        {
            if (loginService.Login(loginDto.Login, loginDto.Password))
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.
                AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, loginDto.Login));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginDto.Login));

                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                var props = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    AllowRefresh = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
                    IsPersistent = true
                };

                HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.
                            AuthenticationScheme, principal, props).Wait();

                return this.Ok(true);
            }
            return this.BadRequest();
        }
```

I used to work with MVC and there was simple solution to generate cookie, add FormsAuthentication - that's it. In .net core it's way more complex and I feel I am stuck now. I am not using built in functions to authenticate users, I generated database myself, roles are not added yet.

Front is made in angular, it can receive either true or false depending on the login state but cookie is not present at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            else
                app.UseHsts();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
                Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
            });

            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
                app.UseCors(x => x
                    .WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000")
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseSecureJwt();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();

            if (Configuration.GetSection("React").Get<ReactOptions>().UseSpa)
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
                app.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer("start");
                });
            }
        }
```

project example :
https://github.com/IonCojucovschi/Boilerplate.AuthDemo/blob/master/AuthDemo.Web/Startup.cs